# Clojure Pedestal root serving as application/octet-stream

Tags: clojure, pedestal

I am trying to host static assets along with services in [Pedestal 0.5.1](http://pedestal.io).  I am using the `::file-path` to point to a directory to host the files. This works fine if I navigate directly to the file http://localhost:8888/index.html but if I go to the root of the site http://localhost:8888 it serves the files as `application/octet-stream` rather than `text/html`.  I adapted the [Hello World Sample](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/tree/master/samples/hello-world) and it has the same behavior.

*src/hello_world/server.clj*

```
(ns hello-world.server
  (:require [io.pedestal.http :as http]
            [io.pedestal.http.route :as route])
  (:gen-class))

(def routes
  (route/expand-routes [[]]))

(def service
  {:env                 :prod
   ::http/join? false
   ::http/routes routes
   ::http/file-path "/tmp/www"       
   ::http/type          :jetty
   ::http/allowed-origins {:creds true :allowed-origins (constantly true)}       
   ::http/port          8888})

(defonce runnable-service (http/create-server service))

(defn -main
  "The entry-point for 'lein run'"
  [& args]
  (println "\nCreating your server...")
  (http/start runnable-service))
```

Start `lein run`

```
$ curl -i localhost:8888
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2016 16:02:56 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 18 Nov 2016 15:10:22 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 12
Server: Jetty(9.3.8.v20160314)

hello world

$ curl -i localhost:8888/index.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2016 16:03:02 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 18 Nov 2016 15:10:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 12
Server: Jetty(9.3.8.v20160314)

hello world
```

Is there some way to fix the "/" route to serve the correct content-type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get correct content-types for files served as directory indexes,
add the interceptor `io.pedestal.http.ring-middlewares/file-info` to
your Pedestal configuration.

This requires that you override the default interceptor chain with
your own, so you will have to include all of the default interceptors
that your app needs.

For example, your service might look something like this:

```
(ns hello-world.service
  (:require
   [io.pedestal.http :as http]
   [io.pedestal.http.ring-middlewares :as middlewares]
   [io.pedestal.http.route :as route]
   [io.pedestal.http.route.definition :refer [defroutes]]))

(defroutes routes
  [[]])

(def service
  {::http/type :jetty
   ::http/port 8080
   ::http/interceptors [http/log-request
                        http/not-found
                        middlewares/session
                        route/query-params
                        (middlewares/file-info)  ; HERE
                        (middlewares/file "/tmp/www")
                        ;; ... insert other interceptors ...
                        (route/router #(deref #'routes) :map-tree)]})
```

For examples of other default interceptors you might want to include,
see [default-interceptors](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/6f23b1088cead0949d329d63a6dfe5f032468ac5/service/src/io/pedestal/http.clj#L180).

### Explanation

This probably does not come up very often in practice because many web
applications use a handler function to generate the home page instead
of returning a static file.

For an alternate solution, you could write a route handler for the `/`
route which returns the contents of `index.html` with the appropriate
content-type.

Pedestal's default interceptor stack includes 
[io.pedestal.http.ring-middlewares/file](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/6f23b1088cead0949d329d63a6dfe5f032468ac5/service/src/io/pedestal/http.clj#L255)
and [io.pedestal.http.ring-middlewares/content-type](https://github.com/pedestal/pedestal/blob/6f23b1088cead0949d329d63a6dfe5f032468ac5/service/src/io/pedestal/http.clj#L249).

These interceptors just wrap the Ring middleware functions
[file-request](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/01de0cf1bbab402905bc65789bebb9a7dc36d974/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/file.clj#L19)
and [content-type-response](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/01de0cf1bbab402905bc65789bebb9a7dc36d974/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/content_type.clj#L6), respectively.

`file-request` returns a `java.io.File` object as the HTTP response.

`content-type-response` examines the *request URI* to determine the
value of the Content-Type header. Since the URI is just `/` it
defaults to `application/octet-stream`.

By contrast `ring.middleware.file-info` (which is deprecated) examines
path of the actual `File` object in the response.
See [file-info-response](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/01de0cf1bbab402905bc65789bebb9a7dc36d974/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/file_info.clj#L34).

`io.pedestal.http.ring-middlewares/file-info` is the interceptor
wrapper around `ring.middleware.file-info/file-info-response`.

Comment: The easiest change might otherwise be to let "/" respond with a redirect to "index.html".